# error when trying to load SQL server 2008 R2 native client x86

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

There's technically 2 problems interlinked with each other here...

I'm currently working on connecting to a mssql database from a website and testing everything through Xampp on a VM. When running the code I get this error on the webpage:

*Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )*

I then follow what it says to do but when I download the x86 version, it tells me that it is not supported on my current OS (this is the same on the 2012 and 2008 R2 edition.. However when I run the x64, it loads perfectly but doesn't solve the error on the website.

Is there a way around this? Am I missing something? I have tried searching this on google and other forums but haven't found anything related.

The details of my VM are:

Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - 64Bit

Any help would be appreciated! and if I've posted in the wrong place, I'm sorry!

Comment: My Google searches revealed a lot of related results, but probably none that will be helpful - turns out that getting 32 bit ODBC drivers to work with 64 bit apps or OSes is difficult to impossible.  My suggestion for a way around this would be to create a VM with a 32 bit OS instead of trying to fit a 32bit ODBC peg into a 64bit OS hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing...

> Are you using both SQL 2012 and 2008 R2?

Either way if the x86 driver does not work but the x64 driver does most likely your application is running in x64 mode and is therefore unable to run the x86 driver.  If you want to use the x86 driver make sure your application is running in x86 mode as well.

Then again, why not run it all in x64 mode anyway?

Comment: The database is running SQL 2008 R2 but the error message is asking for a download for SQL 2012. 

Would you recommend setting up the VM again to run solely the x86 OS?